# Android wear sensor rate changes when "stay awake when charging" enabled

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am currently developing a logging app that collects sensor data from both a smartphone and smartwatch. In the app, there is an option to set the sampling rate. Everything works as intended when both devices are plugged in but when the watch is unplugged it samples at a far higher rate than specified. (e.g. Watch samples at 100Hz when commanded to at 20Hz)

On the watch side, data is collected through a service, which acquires a partial wake lock:

```
mPowerManager = (PowerManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
mWakeLock = mPowerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
mWakeLock.setReferenceCounted(false);
mWakeLock.acquire();
```

I know that the specified sampling rate when registering the sensor listener is only a recommendation to the Android system and depends on the hardware:

```
mSensorManager.registerListener(WearSensorLogService.this, mAccelerometer, samplingRate);
```

However, I can replicate the problem by enabling the "stay awake when charging" setting on the phone (while plugged in obviously). This makes it seem to me that it is a solvable problem and is an issue with some sort of power setting. Any help is appreciated - please let me know if more information about the app is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem in case people come across a similar issue. Turning Wrist Gestures OFF in the settings of the smartwatch helped make the watch collect data exactly at the desired sampling rate.

I think putting the activity out of focus when making the wrist gesture was the problem. However, this is strange because all of the logging is done via a service. Will update post if I have any other findings.